# AngularJS: Restangular controller single quote issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

I'm using restangular to call external API. The GET request works only if I remove the single quotes from controller.  Although, when I try to add an angular chart that fails, unless I add quotes back.  So, one or the other works depending on if added or not. I need both to work so can use data from API for chart. Additionally, I'm not seeing any errors in browsers with or without the quotes.

This is partial app.js

```
var app = angular.module('mymod', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'chart.js', 'restangular'])
      .config(function($routeProvider, RestangularProvider) {
          $routeProvider
              .when('/', {
                  templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
                  controller: MainCtrl // <--- This is what I'm referring to
              })
              .otherwise({
                  redirectTo: '/'
              });

          // Set base url
          RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('https://something.com/api/v1');
          // Auth details
          RestangularProvider.setDefaultHeaders({
              'Authorization': 'Token token=mytoken',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          });
          // Format    
          RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('.json');
          // Data extractor
          RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation) {
              return response.incidents;
          });
      });

  // Graph Example
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
      $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
  });
```

I added 'use strict'; to top of app.js and am now seeing this error: ReferenceError: i is not defined.
Which references the i in for loop below.

```
$scope.update = function(pages) {
for (i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
  Restangular.all("incidents").getList({offset:25 * i, sort_by: "created_on:desc"})
    .then(function(result) {
    Array.prototype.push.apply($scope.incidents,result);
    })
}
};
```

Also, I've been utilizing code example noted below and found a couple problems with it that i've fixed, but I'm new to Angular, so it's been difficult.
reference: [code example](https://github.com/MosheZada/pagerduty-angular/blob/master/app.js)

Comment: It has to be `'MainCtrl'` for sure..

Comment: Can you add the single quotes around MainCtrl in your $routeProvider, and remove the word "app" in "app.controller", so just ".controller..." and see if this helps?

Comment: It seems to me that you're not showing all of the relevant code. If you can get the controller to work properly by referencing it w/a variable or function name (w/out the quotes around it), then you MUST have defined this variable/function somewhere. Yet your definition of the controller does not introduce such a variable. What gives?

Comment: regarding Restangular itself: you may also want to take a look at this SO post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27563040/simple-restangular-example-broken-with-angularjs-1-2) which talks about different versions of AngularJS and what Restangular returns (changed from returning data to returning a promise). Additionally, see the original restangular repo here [link](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular) and scroll down to "Supported Angular versions" for more info.

Comment: Updated with some additional information and provided link with relevant code. Current state is that REST API calls work now with single quotes, but only if 'use strict'; is commented out; but now the chart doesn't work.  If i add 'use strict'; back I get the -  ReferenceError: i is not defined.

Comment: `error: ReferenceError: i is not defined` : you did not declare `i` as a `var` ? should be, e.g. `for (var i =0; i < pages; i++)`

Comment: I'm using Angularjs v1.3.15.  The restangular site states: Restangular supports all angular versions including 1.0.X, 1.1.X and 1.2.X (1.2.4 being the current at the time).   So, maybe a version issue?  Are there any best practices on what to use or not? .. I've been struggling with various issues for awhile now.

Comment: Thank You Shehryar .. Yes, adding missing var fixed the i is not defined error. I guess that was obvious, but dealing with a few different issues my brain was overloaded.  :)